# Changing displayed value depending on a second digit from a number

Tags: vue.js, vue-filter

I have a `vue filter` and display some values. I would like to change the value when the value's last digit is between 2 and 4. I need to have an automatised code so it works for all possible intervals, for example: `(22-24, 32-34, 622-624...)`.
I managed to find the last digit of a value: `value.toString()[value.toString().length - 1]`. I am not sure how to solve this problem, maybe I should come up with a special matematical formula?

```
myfilter: (value): => {
    if(value >= 22 && value <= 24) {
        return 'my new value'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the modulus operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()

```
myfilter: (value): => {
    if(value % 10 <= 4 && value % 10 >= 2 ) {
        return 'my new value'
    }
}
```

Comment: That is another way but my question is how to automatise it.

Comment: @kabugh I don't know what you mean. that does work for all possible intervals. What is your desired output?

Comment: Thanks it does work, but I would like to exclude if the letter before is 1: 12-14, 112-114.